# Docker build image returning error: lambci/lambda : The term 'lambci/lambda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, powershell, aws-lambda

When trying to run docker build command in windows 10 powershell:

```
lambci/lambda: build-python3.7 -t rockar-data/lambda-layers .
```

i get an error like the one below:

```
lambci/lambda: : The term 'lambci/lambda:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ lambci/lambda: build-python3.7 -t school-data/lambda-layers .
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (lambci/lambda::String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get a message like that when the string in question is what is passed directly to powershell as something it should know what to do with. It received `lambci/lambda:` and that's not a path to an executable or a valid command, so it barfs. Look at your script closer and see what's going on with it, somewhere that line is by itself and is messing things up.